# Why ServiceStack MvcHtmlString has no namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, servicestack

In our project in a several places we're using `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString`. After I added reference to ServiceStack assemblies I got compilation error:

`Cannot convert expression type System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString to return type MvcHtmlString`

The collision is between `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString` and `MvcHtmlString` in ServiceStack. In ServiceStack this class has no namespace as you can see in below code or on [github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6ac538ead6cb9980f1d7d24a4c6fd601a06df177/src/ServiceStack/Html/MvcHtmlString.cs)

Is there a good reason for that? Shoudn't this class be in ServiceStack.Html namespace? Namespace has been removed in [last commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/c7503e96608882f7ac7c9acff80b8dae377ba8f2) .

Is there good workaround for it? I had to prefix all occurrences of `MvcHtmlString` with namespace prefix `System.Web.Mvc`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Web;

public sealed class MvcHtmlString : HtmlString
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public MvcHtmlString(string value)
        : base(value ?? String.Empty)
    {
        _value = value ?? String.Empty;
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2104:DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes", Justification = "MvcHtmlString is immutable")]
    public static readonly MvcHtmlString Empty = Create(String.Empty);

    public static MvcHtmlString Create(string value)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(value);
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(MvcHtmlString value)
    {
        return (value == null || value._value.Length == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: this sounds like something you should be adressing on servicestack code site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That commit appears to have been incorrectly reverted into the global namespace. It's been refactored into the `ServiceStack.Html` namespace [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/ce6dd325bdb1eab53fcd1244ba74ee25f57e5f03).

This change is available from v4.0.33+ which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).